# Tool for scripting C enums and constants to C# during build

Tags: c#, c

I have a auto-generated .c file containing const's and enum's I need to access from .Net. I would like to run a pre-build script that would convert the .c file (with C syntax) to a .cs file (with C# syntax). The files are pretty simple so it should be possible to script my way out of this problem.

Here is a section of a .c file

```
#define Bitfile "Test.bit"

static const char* const BitfileSignature = "A6A316954DA417A2F886F3B0035019B1";

typedef enum
{
   ControlBool_TestBool_Address = 0x815E,
   ControlBool_IrqHandshakeWriteToDma_Address = 0x8112,
   ControlBool_WriteToDma_Address = 0x810E,
   ControlBool_stop_Address = 0x813A,
} ControlBool;
```

And I would like to convert that into something like this

```
public static class MyConstants
{
    public static string Bitfile = "Test.bit";
    public static string BitfileSignature = "A6A316954DA417A2F886F3B0035019B1";
}

public enum MyEnum
{
    ControlBool_TestBool_Address = 0x815E,
    ControlBool_IrqHandshakeWriteToDma_Address = 0x8112,
    ControlBool_WriteToDma_Address = 0x810E,
    ControlBool_stop_Address = 0x813A,
}
```

Does anyone know a good tool I could use for this conversion? Preferably a tool that comes with VS2010.

Comment: It would probably be better to generate both `.c` and `.cs` files from same source, if that is an option... Another interesting option might be to have a C# class, which reads the original .c file, parses the data out of it and provides it as properties etc.

Comment: It is an external tool that creates the .c file and it cannot create a c# version of it. I would like to have my addresses stored as enums, so run-time parser is not a good solution for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [T4 Text Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx) to generate your code files from. It's nicely integrated into Visual Studio and once you get the hang of it a fairly easy to use and powerful text templating engine. You'll need to define 2 separate templates (one for C# and one for C) of course.

[EDIT] : It appears i did not read the whole question. The OP problem is converting from C to C#. I still stand by my advice to use T4 in this case but for reading the C source you'll need to write some custom parsing code. Considering that it involves only enum type definitions the parsing code should be fairly trivial. On the other hand if the C defs are already generated from some external definition (like an xml file somewhere) then you could treat that as a data source

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion - I will look into this and get back. FYI: there is no .xml or other source. The .c file is the only source.

Comment: Works like a charm. Easy to learn, flexible - just what I needed. Thanks.